# Are there any limits for TEXT field on a single row?

Tags: mysql

I need to develop an international website. Let's say I have a table called Article:

```
articleID | data | text_EN | text_FR | text_DE | text_ES
```

As you can see a single row contains each version translated of the text. Considering each text field for each language is about 1500 chars there can be any problem for mysql to manage such table?

I heard once that there is an hard limit on how much space can take a single row.

Comment: What happens when you need to add another language? You alter the table?

Comment: Yes.. This way I can have a simpler query than a JOIN with a table containing 1 language for each record

Comment: It's a bad approach to design your app like that..

Comment: I feel perfectly comfortable only with this approach in this case. And it's not like that I am adding language every day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a row size limit in MySQL (64K for MyISAM, around 8K for InnoDB IIRC), but that won't matter much if you're using `TEXT` or `BLOB` fields.

Such fields are actually pointers, the data itself is stored outside of the row. Each `TEXT` field will only take 9 to 12 bytes of row space, according to the [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

That said, I'd second @Bill's advice: article translations would better be stored in rows instead of columns.

Comment: Most probably not, since your five `text_XX` fields will take at most 60 bytes of row storage.

Answer (score 1):

Ok as far as I know everything has its limit.

You can find more info from here.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/

But i think the problem will be solved when you read this.

Answer (score 0):

Describing the row length limit is complicated.  See this blog for details:  [Blob Storage in InnoDB](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/).

But I would strongly recommend that you do not store the text across columns like that.  Store in rows instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Article (
  articeID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  language CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  article_text TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (articleID, language)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: this particular table can't work for me, because I need to store other field too indipendent from language, and this would cause redundancy. If I want to normalize my schema I have to create a second table containing only the translated text, but this would cause a more complex query, and I want to have the query as simple as possibile.